# Oracle sql pattern sorting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a pattern like this - "pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234". I have to extract numbers between ##ind## and ##ind##. Using pl/sql. Suggest

Comment: How many such numbers per input? Just one?

Answer (score 1):

### SQL

```
WITH d
     AS (SELECT 'pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234'       expr,
                '.*[\#]{2}ind[\#]{2}(\d+)[\#]{2}ind[\#]{2}.*' match
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT expr, REGEXP_REPLACE (expr, match, '\1') n
  FROM d
/
```

### PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
   expr    VARCHAR2 (64) := 'pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234';
   match   VARCHAR2 (64) := '.*[\#]{2}ind[\#]{2}(\d+)[\#]{2}ind[\#]{2}.*';
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (REGEXP_REPLACE (expr, match, '\1'));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ESCAPE OFF
DECLARE
    matches VARCHAR2(100) := 'pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234';
    mismatches VARCHAR2(100) := 'pqrst ##id##123456##ind## hggff 1234';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('matches:' || REGEXP_REPLACE(matches
            ,'(.*##ind##(.*)##ind##.*)?.*', '\2'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('mismatches:' || REGEXP_REPLACE(mismatches
            ,'(.*##ind##(.*)##ind##.*)?.*', '\2'));
END;
/
matches:123456
mismatches:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: It will take anything between delimiters, not only numbers

Comment: But if there is no match found then I need to return null. In this case it returns full string... which is logical!!. Wot to do to get null for no match found?

Comment: @AbhijeetSinha: make no mistake in thinking this is efficient, but for small volumes you won't notice performance problems.  And for future questions... make sure to ask a question, and include details like volume, and/or representative examples (which might point out things like non-digits between the markers), and/or expected behavior when a match doesn't occur; the better the question, the less thrash. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select  to_number(trim(
            replace(  
                    replace(
                            'pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234', 
                            SUBSTR('pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234', 1, INSTR('pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234', '#',1,4)), -- <-- 4th occurrence of "#"
                            null), 
                    SUBSTR('pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234', INSTR('pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234', '#',1,5), -- <-- 5th occurrence of "#"
                    length('pqrst ##ind##123456##ind## hggff 1234')), 
                    null)
        )) as result
from dual;
```

Works by identifying 4th and 5th occurrence of '#' and just extracting string from between them.